# How to set a page layout for SharePoint enterprise search result page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, search-results, custom-masterpage, enterprise-search

I applied custom master page for SharePoint enterprise search center site,I can't see the left side web parts like author and other refiners ,Is it possible to set a page layout for result page?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Site Setting > Page Layout and Site Template,
you should be able to set up the preferred layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "special" about the search pages. The web parts work on any page. You just have to configure them. If you have your own page layouts, just create new pages with your page layouts and use them. That means, of course, that your designers have to account for the layout of the search center pages.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. If I create a pages library and look through the available layouts, none of them match the design of a search results page. Is it possible to get that layout without being in a search center site?

Comment: You can if you enable the Publishing Features on the site. (There may also be another feature like Search Page types, but I haven't done it in a while.) If you look at the features enabled on the Enterprise Search Center template you can figure it out.

Comment: thanks. I was able to figure it out. If I remember correctly I have to enable "SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features"